# Auth0 customize logo

Tags: c#, wpf, auth0

I am following the wpf auth0 login example. I am not clear on what is the best method to customize logo / icon ?

```
icon: 'https://auth0.com/boot/badge.png'
```

I have added a full Auth0.Windows project to the solution, where I am appending css and js to the html in the UpdateStatus(string message) once login window is loaded, which feels hackish way of doing it. Any Advises or samples would be helpful.

```
 var auth0 = new Auth0Client(AuthDomain, ClientId);
 var userAthenticate = await auth0.LoginAsync(null);
```

Answer (score 2):

### Edit: Just realized this was 8 months old... sorry for the resurrection.

You should be able to supply a third param to Auth0Client...

```
    var options = {
        theme: {
            logo: '/images/logo.png'
        }
    };
    var auth0 = new Auth0Client(AuthDomain, ClientId, options);
```